# Androidアプリで、activity_main.xml以外の場所でタブを表示させたい。

Tags: android, fragment

AndroidStudioでAndroidアプリを作っています。
今回、`fragment_main.xml`にタブを実装しようと思い、以下のコードを書きました。
（１つ目のタブ、タブ１をタップすると下にカレンダー＋テキストビューが出てきて、２つ目のタブ、タブ２をタップするとテキストビューのみ出てくる）
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

しかし、xmlのプレビューではちゃんと表示されているものの、エミュレーターを実行すると落ちてしまい、
`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TabHost.setup()' on a null object referencef`というエラーがでてきました。

`fragment_main.xml`の中身を`activity_main.xml`に書くときちんとタブがでてくるのですが、なぜ`fragment_main.xml`に書くとエラーになってしまうのか分かりません。
ちなみに`fragment_main.xml`は、アプリを起動したときに最初に表示される場面です。

`fragment_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <CalendarView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0px"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:clickable="true">

                </CalendarView>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="#ccc"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0px"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:text="MEMO"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView-タブ2" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

`MainActivity.java`のタブに関係する部分

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

    TabHost tabhost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    tabhost.setup();

//ここからタブに関する部分
    TabHost.TabSpec tab1 = tabhost.newTabSpec("tab1");
    tab1.setIndicator("タブ１");
    tab1.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    tabhost.addTab(tab1);

    TabHost.TabSpec tab2 = tabhost.newTabSpec("tab2");
    tab2.setIndicator("タブ2");
    tab2.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    tabhost.addTab(tab2);

    tabhost.setCurrentTab(0);
}
```

`activity_main.xml`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.example.yuriyuri.toolbar.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

---

`変更後のonCreate内`

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

    PlaceholderFragment placeholderFragment = PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(1);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container,placeholderFragment).commit();


    TabHost tabhost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    tabhost.setup();


    TabHost.TabSpec tab1 = tabhost.newTabSpec("tab1");
    tab1.setIndicator("タブ１");
    tab1.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    tabhost.addTab(tab1);

    TabHost.TabSpec tab2 = tabhost.newTabSpec("tab2");
    tab2.setIndicator("タブ2");
    tab2.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    tabhost.addTab(tab2);

    tabhost.setCurrentTab(0);

}
```

`PlaceholderFragment のクラス`

```
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }
}
```

Comment: `MainActivity.javaのタブに関する部分`はどこに記述していますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。タブに関する部分は、MainActivity.javaのonCreateメソッド内に記述しています。質問文のコードも直しておきました。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fragment_main.xml を使う Fragment が、Activity の onCreate の処理の段階では、まだ Attach されていないので、その fragment_main.xml の中にある、tabhost を findViewById しても、見つけられず、null になっていると思います。

tabhost を findViewById して見つける前に、当該 Fragment を用意して Activity に Attach する処理を書けば、解消されるのではないでしょうか？（または、activity_main.xml に当該 Fragment を含めておくか）

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    TabHost tabhost = (TabHost) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    tabhost.setup();

    // ここからタブに関する部分
    TabHost.TabSpec tab1 = tabhost.newTabSpec("tab1");
    tab1.setIndicator("タブ１");
    tab1.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    tabhost.addTab(tab1);

    TabHost.TabSpec tab2 = tabhost.newTabSpec("tab2");
    tab2.setIndicator("タブ2");
    tab2.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    tabhost.addTab(tab2);

    tabhost.setCurrentTab(0);

    return rootView;
}
```

注記：MainActivity の onCreate で Fragment をアタッチする処理を書くなりする、と先に述べましたが、Activity 側が onCreate の段階では、Fragment 側も未だ、onCreateView が終っていませんで、これではまだ駄目でした。

本筋としては、Fragment 側の onCreateView で処理するのが一番です。どうしても、Activity 側で処理を書きたいのであれば、Fragment 側の onCreateView が確実に終ったタイミングのところで行わねばなりません（onPostCreate とか？）。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。なるほどと思い当該フラグメント＝PlaceHoldarFragmentをAttachするため、
`PlaceholderFragment placeholderFragment = PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(1);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container,placeholderFragment).commit();`
と書いたのですが、まったく同じエラーが出てしまいました。
補足は質問文に追加しますね。
すみません、`activity_main.xml に当該 Fragment を含めておく`というのがよく分からずできませんでした。

Comment: プロジェクトテンプレートの PlaceholderFragment（MainActivity の内部 public static class）を使っているのですね？　それであれば（というか本来は）、tabhost に関する処理は、Fragment 側に処理させるのが、本筋なのですが、onCreateView の中でやらせるわけにはいかないでしょうか？

Comment: @しろな 回答を onCreateView によるものに更新しました。

Comment: おっしゃる通りでした。onCreateViewの中で行わせたところ無事タブが表示されました。知識不足で申し訳ないです、本当にありがとうございます！！